How to create long-time execute server process with callback in Node.JS
I make backend what will be eventually will working in Google Cloud.
All my API perform from Frontend and I must answer quickly as possible.
However, I need to create a couple of API with long time calculation and with callback when calculation ended
So, I need answer immediately, than need to doing some calculation with calling 3-rd party API and a lot of waiting, and than I need to notify my Frontend.
What correct pattern to doing this?

Notifying a client from the server can be done a number of ways: client polling via http using a job code, webSocket/socket.io message, server sent events (SSE).

I don't know now what way we need to select, in previous backand I used SignarR, but it was worked from separate task, created by quartz.  Currently I don't know what way I need to select because Frontend doing another programmer. My current task is create most universal solution and start separate task for long operation. And maybe with Google Cloud future, but I don't sure - is it need? Or there is more useful and simple way?

and part of that backend task based on MySQL trigger, unfortunately this is AWS deployed MySQL, any notification is impossible maybe. And I don't know how to create notification from MySQL trigger to my frontend, but maybe this is another question, periodic query to MySQL also impossible, because this is high loading application

If you're trying to ask a specific question about MySQL in AWS, then you need to change up your whole question and ask about that.  You don't ask new questions in the comments.  So far, this question is wandering over a whole bunch of topics and unclear exactly what you're asking on any of them.

what concrete packages I need to use? Or some functionality of Google Cloud can help me?

yes, notification based on AWS MySQL trigger - this is another question, I understand. My current question is about create long time server task and notification to frontend. What packages I can use, what concrete pattern?

A good backend pattern could be a PUT URL which immediately returns a status 202 (Accepted) to the original request (with a payload containing the URL of the eventual result).
Hitting the URL of the eventual result on a poll (e.g. every few seconds) will continue to serve some status (e.g. 404) until eventually it serves a 200 when the result is eventually prepared and the poll can stop.
The exact statuses that make sense for your case will vary depending on what is going on, but the basics are there, and the corresponding client-side routine could be shipped as a isomorphic module using fetch or axios.

Thanks, dear @cefn, but I don't understand you. Can you explain me more details, please. How I can simultaneously return 202 and create long task? And than, when task ended, how I can notify my frontend? Can you see some example for me? To be honest I have no multithreading experience with Node, only like new Promise. And most trouble for me that my software can be finally deployed to Google Cloud and I'm don't sure how mutlithreading packages will working and Google Cloud at all. One case is Node in own Virtual Machine, Google Cloud this is opposite environment, isn't it?

The implementation would be to use a HTTP client (like Axios) to make an original request for the 'long time calculation'. The server responds immediately with a status that indicates a task is in progress, and returns a URL you can keep hitting to find out how the task is going. In client-side logic, there would be a loop with a delay which keeps requesting that same task-specific URL. The loop keeps going as long as it's getting a status indicating the task's still in progress, such as 202 or 404. When it finally gets a 200 status the response contains the result of the long-running request.
